# represent things that share some basic characteristics and have custom data in a database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm working on an application that needs to keep track of physical places in the world that are hierarchically related - berth, terminal, port, country. They all share some basic characteristics, like a name or geofence. Some of them may have a physical street address. And they also all have custom data, like a port has a UN/LOCODE. A country has a country code. A terminal may have a company that operates it.

One approach is to have a table per thing - so a "port" table and a "country" table and a "berth" terminal, etc. Berth would have a terminal_id, terminal would have a port_id, port would have a country_id...

Another approach is to have a general table called "place" with a property called "type". And then place could have a parent_id.

Or you could have a place_to_place table to allow for many-to-many relationships.

How should I represent such things that share some basic characteristics and have custom data in a database?

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)